# Issues with dragging an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom-events

I am attempting to have an image be dragged between two locations and then move around when it gets there.  My image, which is the dogpic, is draggable and will drag into the area of the dogpark but will not actually drop in there, like it will not move and just snaps back to it's original place.  I am not sure how to fix this and would appreciate any help.

Attached HTML/Javascript Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<h>CMPSC Class</h>
<p>Lab 5</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<div id = "doghouse" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)"; ondrop="drop(event)">
<img id = "dh"; height = 320; width = 320; src = "http://images.clipartpanda.com/doghouse-clipart-ilmp-dog_house.jpg", style = "left: 0; top: 0; position: relative" ></img>
<img id = "dogpic" src = "http://images.clipartpanda.com/cartoon-20clipart-20free-cartoon_dog_clip_art_22216.jpg"; height = 100; width = 100; style = "position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 112px"; draggable="true"; ondrag="drag(event)"></img>
</div>
<div id = "park"><img id = "dpark"; height = 600; width = 600; src = "http://www.clipartidy.com/wp-content/uploads/hd/hd-new-design-plans-for-broadway-hill-park-unveiled-graphic.jpg"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)"; ondrop="dragfunction(event)"></img></div>
<script>
var b = document.getElementById("dogpic");
b.addEventListener("drag", drop(event), false);
b.addEventListener("drag", drag(event), false);
b.addEventListener("drag", allowDrop(event), false);
function drop(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if(event.target.id = "park"){
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    img.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
    img.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
    setTimeout(dragfunction(event), 3000);
  }
  if(event.target.id = "doghouse"){
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}
function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
</html>
```